# How to write array of dtype: float64 into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to stackoverflow, but I'm really hoping that someone can help!

I've read a csv file of numbers into python, and then done a series of calculations  with them, and now want to output the new data into a new csv file. However I think I might be confused in what the output is and so am not calling the correct format to save the data. If anyone has any help/suggestions I'd much appreciate it. Below is an outline of what I've done...

The [original csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XO2V.jpg) I've read the data from

Code I'm using:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Read the file in csv 
DATA = pd.read_csv("for_sof.csv")

# Extract the columns of bin counts from the csv
Bin0 = DATA.iloc[:,2]
Bin1 = DATA.iloc[:,3]
Bin2 = DATA.iloc[:,4]
Bin3 = DATA.iloc[:,5] 

# calculations on the data from the original csv
Values_A = (((math.pi * Bin0) / 6 ) / 100 ) * 1.05
Values_B = (((math.pi * Bin1) / 6 ) / 100 ) * 1.05
Values_C = (((math.pi * Bin2) / 6 ) / 100 ) * 1.05
Values_D = (((math.pi * Bin2) / 6 ) / 100 ) * 1.05

# the data I want in the new csv file
London = Values_A + Values_B
Manchester = Values_C + Values_D
Number = DATA.iloc[:,0]

# writing the data to file
csvfile = "output_file.csv"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for val in Number:
        writer.writerow([val])
    for val in London:
        writer.writerow([val])
    for val in Manchester:
        writer.writerow([val])

# checking the data type
print "London", London
print "Manchester", Manchester
```

[The ouput_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA2ep.jpg) which only has the "Number" data, which I extracted from the original csv file and copied into the new one.

The output of [print "London", London](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV3iF.jpg) showing the format and dtype: float64

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Pandas for reading the CSV but not using Pandas for writing the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing a single-column CSV with first all the `Number` values, then all the `London` values, then all the `Manchester` values.

If you want a three-column CSV where each row has `Number`, `London`, and `Manchester` values, by iterating the three sequences in lock-step, the way to do that is with `zip`:

```
with open(csvfile, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for number, london, manchester in zip(Number, London, Manchester):
        writer.writerow([number, london, manchester])
```

---

However, you're using Pandas, and the whole point of Pandas is to avoid having to worry about this kind of stuff. You're already using it to read the CSV and turn it into a nice `DataFrame` with a trivial one-liner using `read_csv`. If you build a nice `DataFrame` with the output you want in the format you want, you can likewise use Pandas to write it to a CSV with a trivial one-liner using [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv).

This could be as simple as:

```
outdf = pd.DataFrame()
outdf['Number'] = DATA.iloc[:,0]
outdf['London'] = Values_A + Values_B
outdf['Manchester'] = Values_C + Values_D
outdf.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```